# Particle Instance modifier : Keeping dead particles more than one frame

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, instances

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a nice liquid splatter effect with a particle system. I avoid fluid simulation cause It can get to very time consuming.

I want to have a pound of liquid + motion blur on the drops.

I'm using a particle instance to separate the dead particles from the particle system. The point is to use a geometry node modifier to create the pound.

It works perfectly on the viewport. But only when I hit play from the 1st frame.

It seems that the dead particles only last for one frame otherwise. Plus it doesn't work when rendered.

*Viewport result :*
[image]

*Rendered image :*
[image]

Is there anyway to accumulate the dead particles ?

*My setup :*
[image]

The particle system is baked.

**Thank you !!**